# Как из значений массива, построить обращение к объекту JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив :

```
[grandparent, parent, children]
```

Как из него сделать такую конструкцию?

```
obj[grandparent][parent][children]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, то у вас есть какое-то значение в объекте, и массив свойств, где значение лежит:

```
var obj = { grandparent: { parent: { children: 'Johnny' } } };
// obj.grandparent.parent.children = 'Johnny';

var properties = ['grandparent', 'parent', 'children'];
```

И если нужно получить значение (в примере - `Johnny`), то нужно просто циклом пройтись по значениям массива, сохраняя при этом ссылку на предыдущий объект:

```
var value = obj;
properties.forEach(function (name) {
    value = value[name] || {};
});
console.log(value); // Johnny
```

Более красивый вариант с использованием `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
var that = obj; // если в качестве объекта у вас будет this
var value = properties.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev[curr] || {};
}, that);
console.log(value); // Johnny
```

`Array.prototype.reduce` + `ecmascript6`:

```
var value = properties.reduce((p, c) => p[c] || {}, obj);
console.log(value); // Johnny
```

---

`|| {}` в каждом примере я использовал данную конструкцию, которая в случае, если свойста не существует, не будет вываливать ошибку (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined` ) на следующий шагах, и в итоге результатом будет пустой объект. Если все дочернии объекты точно существуют, эту конструкцию можно убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вот простой вариант:

```
function arrayToObj(arr) {

    var obj = {};

    if (arr.length > 0) {

        obj[arr.shift()] = arrayToObj(arr);

        return obj;
    }

    return null;
}

arrayToObj(['grandparent', 'parent', 'children'])


// Вернется { grandparent: { parent: { children: null } } }
// можно обратиться как:
var obj = arrayToObj(['grandparent', 'parent', 'children'])
obj.grandparent.parent.children
// или
obj['grandparent']['parent']['children']
```

Comment: Нужно получить значение свойства объекта. Но названия свойств лежат в массиве. Элемент массива под индексом 0, то есть первый должен быть подставлен первым. Если мы имеем [grandparent, parent, children], то вызывать значение свойства нужно так this.grandparent.parent.children